# Implementing a radio button which toggles other radio buttons

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

A current project I'm working on involves a form which consumes a model with a list of items.

```
public class BatchModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; 
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

I update statuses in the form using radio buttons:

```
// declare some list of assignable statuses, statusList

// create radio button for each object
for(int i = 0; i < batch.Items.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(j => batch.Items[i].IdInventory, batch.Items[i].IdInventory);
    @foreach (var status in statusList)
    {
        <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(j => batch.Items[i].ItemAssignedStatus, status)</td>
    }
}
```

I would like to also have a 'Master' radio button at the top of the form which toggles all radios in the form to the given value; how can I achieve this?

Comment: Client side, or server side? That is, does toggling the button submit the page and re-render it (so code would be C#) or does it happen client side (javascript). It's pretty easy to do if you use a proper class or attribute to target with JS to just set the values, but your html needs to be structured for it so you can use name or class or whatever to select the items

Comment: @Nikki9696 I think it would be better to do client-side, if possible. I don't mind writing some javascript and changing some classes to do it.

Comment: Jquery, or vanilla?

Comment: vanilla; my team hates jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example using only JS and HTML. I think it will help you structure your generated code as needed.

```js
function toggleit(element) {
   let value = element.value;
   let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleit[value='" + value + "']");
   for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].checked = true;   
        }
   
}
```

```html
<div>Master
<input type="radio" name="master" value="on" id="master_on" onchange="toggleit(this)"  />
<label for="master_on">On</label>
<input type="radio" name="master" value="off" id="master_off" onchange="toggleit(this)"  />
<label for="master_off">Off</label>
</div>
<div>
<div>Foo
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="on" id="foo_on" class="toggleit" />
<label for="foo_on">On</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="off" id="foo_off" class="toggleit" />
<label for="foo_off">Off</label>
</div>
<div>Bar
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="on" id="bar_on" class="toggleit" />
<label for="bar_on">On</label>
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="off" id="bar_off" class="toggleit" />
<label for="bar_off">Off</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been struggling with this for several hours, and I could never get the js syntax quite right!